# CodeIgniter + Nginx + PHP-FPM on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, osx-lion, php

So I have installed Nginx and PHP-FPM via Homebrew, but to NO avail have I been able to actually get my local system up and running.

I keep receiving the Nginx 502 Bad Gateway error.

Here is my Nginx.conf

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    charset                   utf-8;
    source_charset            utf-8;
    ignore_invalid_headers    on;
    server_name_in_redirect   off;

#    keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    tcp_nopush  on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    index index.html index.php;

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Vhost File:

```
server {
    index index.htm index.php index.html
    listen   80;
    server_name  site.local;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.local_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site.local_error.log;

    root   /Users/dennismonsewicz/Sites/site;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|pdf|txt|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$
        {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        # Serve the directoy/file if it exists, else pass to CodeIgniter front controller
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

PHP-FPM.conf file

```
[global]
pid = /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.10/var/run/php-fpm.pid
daemonize = yes

[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = dennismonsewicz
group = staff
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 500
```

Comment: Check your nginx error logs. Chances are it is erroring on something specific and that will help you figure out what / where.

Comment: this is the error I keep getting... `2012/02/13 14:56:33 [error] 72163#0: *32 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: site.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "site.local:8080"`

Comment: That has to do with your php-fpm settings. First up, are you sure fpm is running, and running on port 9000? Second, can you post your fpm conf file and the `pool.d/*.conf` file you are using?

Comment: I posted my fpm conf file. It is running on port 9000. I can get a normal index.php to load with a simple `phpinfo()` but for some reason it throws up when trying to load this site

Comment: So it has to be something with the site I am trying to setup... I was able to run a brand new codeigniter app with no issues whatsoever on its own vhost and everything...

Comment: Try with `fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;` and `fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;` in location ~ \.php$ section